# Python обработка csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

есть csv файл, в нем 4 столбца и 500 строк
Например:
Номер-Наименование-Сумма-Дата

Как можно обработать данную таблицу для получения следующего:

1. Сложить таблицу - Из всех строк, где Наименование и Дата совпадает сделать одну и получить итоговую сумму для этих строк.

Например из:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `pandas.read_csv` и `DataFrame.groupby("Наименование", "Дата").agg()` Вам в помощь.

Comment: @Vovin Прямо `.sum()` можно конкретно

Comment: Спасибо.
А можно потом сразу разместить таблицу по другому:
Числа слева(вертикально), Номера сверху(горизонтально), а суммы на пересечении?